# some confusion in little picard theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Little Picard Theorem :
A nonconstant entire function $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C }$ omits at most one complex value $a \in \mathbb{C}$

Now  Give three   example  of Little Picard Theorem ?

My attempt  : I found  only  one example  that is

$f(z)= e^z$ only

How  can i find  the  other  two example  ?

Comment: $z$ and $z^2{}$? I mean, you are looking for examples of a property that *all noncostant entire functions* have.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path  but ur example  doesnot omit  at most  one  complex value

Comment: "Zero" is "at most one".

Comment: i thinks  0  is  empty  i mean  0 will not counts

Comment: @SaucyO'Path i take $ f(z) = e^z$ but here  $f(z)  \neq  0$ that is  f is  omits 0  here    but  in ur cases $ f(z) = z$ or $z^2$  does n't  omit  $0$ i mean $f(z) =0$

Comment: So I guess you want examples of entire functions which omit exactly one complex value.

Comment: ya @SaucyO'Path   u gots  the points

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only functions that miss exactly one point are of the form $e^{g(z)} +a$, where $g(z)$ is entire and $a$ is a constant (of course, $a$ is the complex number that the function will miss) . So for your other examples, you could do stuff like $e^{z^2}$ and $e^{\sin(z)}+5$.

The reason why you can only have $e^{g(z)}+a$ is due to the [Weierstrass Factorization Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem). In short, it says that any entire function can be represented as

$$z^m e^{g(z)} \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n(z/a_n)$$

where the list $a_1, a_2, ...$ is a list of all the (non-zero) zeroes of $f$ (where a zero with multiplicity $k$ appears $k$ times in the list), $g(z)$ is an entire function, and the $E_n$ are called canonical factors, with $E_n(z) = (1-z)e^{z+z^2/2+z^3/3 + \cdots + z^n/n}$. As you can see, the $E_n(z/a_n)$ vanishes exactly at $a_n$ because of the $1-z$ part, and the $e^{\cdots}$ part is just there to make the product converge for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Now going back to the original problem, suppose that $f$ is entire and misses $a$. Then $f(z) -a$ is entire and has no zeroes, so  $f(z)-a = e^{g(z)}$, and thus $f(z) = e^{g(z)}+a$.

**EDIT:** Thinking about it more, there is no reason to bring in the Weierstrass Theorem. There is a simpler theorem which says that if $g(z)$ holomorphic on a simply connected region $\Omega$ (which $\mathbb{C}$ is) and never vanishes, then there is a function $h(z)$ such that $\forall(z \in \Omega): g(z) = h(z)$. Again, if $f(z)$ misses $a$, then $f(z)-a$ never vanishes, so it is equal to $e^{h(z)}$, and thus $f(z) = e^{h(z)} + a$.